# UITableView rows are buggy when navigating to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, uiviewcontroller

I have a TableView in my application which displays some events. When I click on it, it navigates to the event clicked. 
My struggle is, that the whole navigation process / animation looks very ugly. The rows disappear when the new ViewController is already present.

I managed to screenshot it, so you could understand better how it looks.
[image: Tableview]
[image: Navigation]

Code looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    guard let parent = parentVC else { return }
    guard let id = twoDimensionalEventArray[indexPath.section].events[indexPath.row].eventID else { return }
    parent.gotoEvent(eventID: id)
}

func gotoEvent(eventID: Int) {
    let event = eventArray[eventID]
    let eventVC = SingleEventViewController(event: event)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(eventVC, animated: true)
}
```

Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Because two people suggested I provide my Viedloading of the SingleEventVuewController, here it is:

```
init(event: Event) {
    thisEvent = event
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    setupDefaultValues()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    applyDefaultValues()
    setupNavBar()
    setupViews()
    confBounds()
    getSnapshotForLocation()
}
```

Comment: Is your first `viewController`s view is transparent?

Comment: push your viewcontroller in main thread and check once

Comment: if you mean it's backgroundColor is set to .clear, yes.

Comment: please do not set the backgroundColor to clear. Its causing this tranperancy

Comment: Pushing in main thread doesn't change anything, sadly.

Comment: I set it to white and the issue is still there

Comment: can you share the code for viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear for the detail view controller?

Comment: I set the detail viewcontrollers background to white and now it works.

Comment: I knew it. Please try to avoid clear color as much as possible, its quite graphics intensive.

Comment: You could post this as an answer. I'll give you your credit for it.

Comment: show SingleEventViewController code on load and appear, something wrong there surely

Comment: okay, I did that by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the backgroundColor to white like `self.view.backgroundColor = .white` in `viewDidLoad()` of the detail view controller or you could set it in storyboard if you done it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Set background color content view of cell as white in storyboard . Please refer the screenshot [image]

Comment: I have never used storyboards in my projects.

Comment: In this method ->     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                                         cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }